# While Executing this code am facing the following error as Error :Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Tags: document-library, csom

```
using System;


using System.Collections.Generic;


using System.Linq;


using System.Text;


using System.Threading.Tasks;


using Microsoft.SharePoint;


using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


using System.Security;


using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;


using System.IO;





namespace DocMoveTool


{

class Program


{


    public static string getstudentId = string.Empty;


    public static string getStudentcurrentStatus = string.Empty;


    public static string getStudenAddInf = string.Empty;


    public static string getLookid = string.Empty;


    public static string getStudenLoc = string.Empty;


    public static int strFileCount;


    public static string logFilePath = @"D:\Logs\Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";//required to provide this path for storing logs 


    public static string subfolderName = string.Empty;





    public static int Parentfilescount;


    public static string educationsection = "ABC";//metadata column name has to be initialize here 



    public static void Main(string[] args)


    {

                           //enter library name from where you want to copy 


        /

        string strDislib = "Test Doc";                      //enter destination library to where you want to copy 




        string userName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";             //login credentials 





        Console.WriteLine("Enter your password.");


        SecureString password = GetPassword();


        try


        {


            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("XXXXXXXXXXXXX/"))        // operating site URL 


            {


                string createtxt = "";


                WriteLog(createtxt);


                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);


                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strDislib);


                // GetTermIdForTerm(clientContext); 


                getfilefromSource(clientContext, strDislib, strSourcelib);                  // initial point for the moving of documents 

                // testmethod(clientContext, strDislib, strSourcelib); 

            }


        }


        catch (Exception ex)

        {


            Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + ex.Message);


            string errorMsg = ex.Message;


            WriteLog("Error :" + errorMsg);


        }


    }

    private static void getfilefromSource(ClientContext clientContext, string strDislib, string strSourcelib)


    {
        try


        {

            string targetFileUrl = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + strDislib + "/";

            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strSourcelib);

            List dislist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(strDislib);

            clientContext.Load(dislist);


            clientContext.Load(dislist.RootFolder);

            clientContext.Load(dislist.RootFolder.Folders);


            clientContext.Load(dislist.RootFolder.Files);

            clientContext.Load(list);


            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);


            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);                                                       // we are loading all folders 


            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);                                                          // loading files 

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;


            List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();


            int i = 0;


            foreach (Folder f in fcol)                                                      //iterating through folder collection 

            {


                if (f.Name.ToString().Trim() != "Forms")


                {

                    string getstudentId = string.Empty;


                    string getStudentcurrentStatus = string.Empty;


                    string getStudenAddInf = string.Empty;


                    string getStudenLoc = string.Empty;


                    string strStuid = string.Empty;


                    string strStuName = string.Empty;


                    string strStuIdName = string.Empty;


                    string foldername = string.Empty;


                    subfolderName = string.Empty;

                    foldername = f.Name.ToString();



                   int getcount = foldername.Length - 6 ;(eg:12345, Sachin Reddy)


                   strStuid = foldername.Substring(0, 5);                  //Extracting Student ID 


                   strStuName = foldername.Substring(6, getcount);         //Extracting Student Name 


                     //strStuName= strStuName.First().ToString().ToUpper() +String.Join("", strStuName.Skip(1)).ToLower();// fisrt Uppercase,remaining Lowercase 


                   strStuIdName = strStuid + " - " + strStuName;          //40581-student name 





                    // Forms 


                    if (i < 500)


                    {


                        moveDoc(clientContext, strDislib, strSourcelib, f, targetFileUrl, dislist, subfolderName, strStuIdName, strStuName, strStuid);//parent level folder Files will move alone 


                        string getfolderName = f.Name.ToString();


                        FolderCollection subfcol = f.Folders;


                        clientContext.Load(subfcol);


                        clientContext.Load(subfcol);


                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        int subfolderCount = subfcol.Count;


                        if ((subfolderCount == 0) && (Parentfilescount == 0))           // if parent level folder files moving is completed and there are no sub folders then paarent folder will get deleted 


                        {


                            Web web = clientContext.Web;


                            var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(f.ServerRelativeUrl);


                            folder.DeleteObject();


                            web.Context.ExecuteQuery();


                            string logmsg = "Deleted folder from source " + f.Name;


                            Console.WriteLine(logmsg);

                            WriteLog(logmsg);


                        }


                        else


                        {


                            string logInsidesubfolder1 = f.Name + " Subfolder is available for current folder and hence cannot delete current folder";





                            Console.WriteLine(logInsidesubfolder1);


                            // WriteLog(logInsidesubfolder); 


                            foreach (Folder subf in subfcol)

                            {

                                subfolderName = subf.Name.ToString();

                                string logInsidesubfolder = subf.Name + " Subfolder is available. Reading files in Subfolder has been initialized";

                                Console.WriteLine(logInsidesubfolder);


                                WriteLog(logInsidesubfolder);


                                moveDoc(clientContext, strDislib, strSourcelib, subf, targetFileUrl, dislist, subfolderName, strStuIdName, strStuName, strStuid);//Moving Subfolder documents 



                            }


                            CheckFiles(clientContext, strDislib, strSourcelib, f);//this function will check wheter folder and subfolder are having files or not also delete the tree if there are no files available 


                        }


                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("All files moved ,folder Name :" + f.Name.ToString());//confirmation message for moving all files 


                    Console.WriteLine("Count :" + i);


                    i++;


                }





            }


        }


        catch (Exception e)


        {


            string errorMsg = e.Message;


            WriteLog("Error :" + errorMsg);


        }


    }
```

Comment: It is not full code. Try to add 2 brackets to the end. - }}

Comment: Did you try to debug? in what line an exception was occurred?

Comment: yeah i did am getting                         int getcount = foldername.Length - 6 ;(eg:12345, Sachin Reddy)
 strStuid = foldername.Substring(0, 5);    //Extracting Student ID 
 strStuName = foldername.Substring(6, getcount);         //Extracting Student Name 


                     //strStuName= strStuName.First().ToString().ToUpper() +String.Join("", strStuName.Skip(1)).ToLower();// fisrt Uppercase,remaining Lowercase 


                   strStuIdName = strStuid + " - " + strStuName;          //40581-student name 
in these lines

Comment: Yes this is not a full code i just copied the first part where am getting the error.

Comment: try to comment (eg:12345, Sachin Reddy) and define line when error has been occurred.